# Внести значения в имеющийся массив

Tags: php, массивы

Есть такой массив

```
[
 [1575400382,"Test","","","Строка1",1,69],
 [1575400382,"Test","","","Строка2",1,69]
]
```

Как я могу добавить в него строку,например чтобы было так

```
[
 [1575400382,"Test","","","Строка1",1,69],
 [1575400382,"Test","","","Строка2",1,69],
 [1575400382,"Test","","","Строка3",1,69]
]
```

Вот так создается и пишется массив в коде

```
//===========================
$chat = array(json_decode(file_get_contents("chat_log.php")));
$chat[] = array_push(time(), $username, $to_login['1'], $private['1'], $msg_text, ($config['color'] + 0), $lastId);
file_put_contents("chat_log.php", json_encode($chat));
```

Требуется именно такой вид массива(чат от одной онлайн игры,пытаюсь оживить)

Comment: array_push($chat, [time(), ...]);

Answer (score 0):

```
    $chat = json_decode(file_get_contents("chat_log.php"));
$result = count($chat);
    //if ($session->user['authlevel'] == 0)
    //  $msg_text = 'цветочки';

    $chat[$result++] = array(time(), $username, $to_login['1'], $private['1'], $msg_text, ($config['color'] + 0), $lastId);
    //cache::set("game_chat", json_encode($chat), 86400);
    file_put_contents("chat_log.php", json_encode($chat));
    die('1');
```

Весь вопрос решился просто,сразу не подумал.Считаю к-во элементов **$result = count($chat);** в массиве,далее при записи нового сообщения делаю так **$chat[$result++]** и все,запись встает как надо в нужном порядке.

Comment: $chat[$result++] это тоже самое, что $chat[], а вообще-то, я вам тое самое написал в коменте

Comment: @splash58 в комменте вы какую то шляпу с `array_push` написали

Comment: @splash58, ваш метод в обще не работает))

Comment: @UrbanSide там просто `_push` лишнее, не удалил наверное. `$result++` тут не надо, достаточно как написано `$chat[] = ...`

Comment: Во, поправил :)